# Beyond Cox Regression, what are good ways to compare two populations life expectancy/mortality rates given health parameters through time?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, survival, descriptive-statistics, cox-model

I am given two datasets, from which I am seeking to evaluate if there is any difference in life expectancy/mortality rates between these two male population datasets (approx. 500 and 2000 data points from each group). If curious, one is a group that has been exposed to a certain threshold of a type of radiation, and the other no radiation.

Various health parameters (systolic / diastolic blood pressure, total cholesterol, Blood glucose, BMI, etc.) are accessed bi-yearly throughout the multi-decade study. Some data from the control population B are censured (meaning they dropped out (didn't hear from them) part of the way through the study), but this is a small percentage of just the control population. Additionally, these individuals in the control population B were actually matched in these health parameters from the start of the study with individuals of population A (in other words, an individual in the control population B was specifically chosen because it matched a subject in the test population A in terms of its health parameters at the start).

Thus far, I am looking at implementing a Cox Proportional-Hazards Model to look at the hazard ratios between the two cohorts as well as Kaplan-Meier curves which obviously can still make use of the censured data.

But I am curious if there are other suggestions for analyses which could be run given this scenario using traditional statistics or machine learning. Not just in terms of comparing the two populations mortality rates relative to one another, but also in terms of simply predicting life expectancy on each dataset individually (for instance, using an LSTM network to predict life expectancy similar to a Dutch study which used electronic medical records to predict life expectancies).